# After including DNS forwarder, not possibility to send email to the "forwarded domain"

Tags: domain-name-system, email, forwarding

I have a client non trusted domain, let say "domainA.com", I manage it with System Center 2012 installed in my company internal domain (let say domainB.lan). I have added forwarders in my dns to be able to make address resolution for domainA.com. Everything works fine. Except when i send email to (for example) xyz@domainA.com... My exchange server then try to send them to the forwarders (AD integrated DNS Servers) internal to the domainA... Kind of a split brain dns situation.. To make things worse, the company "DomainA.com" does not have its own exchange, but use a service provider for emails...
Any idea on how can i solve this??

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. Your email server doesn't try to send the email to the DNS forwarders for the remote domain. Your email server tries to resolve the MX record for the remote domain using the forwarders that you configured for that domain.
2. The DNS servers for the remote domain don't have an MX record for the domain, which is to be expected in an internal DNS zone.
3. Have the person who manages the remote DNS servers add an MX record for the domain that points to the public A record for the email server of the remote domain.

Comment: Thank you, that was it.. I added the mx record this morning to the companyA dns, and now it works!

Comment: Glad to help...